# Starting an activity with large intent extras

Tags: android, serialization

I am starting an activity with a `Serializeable` extra.  This extra contains a `List` of a custom object holding a bunch of types, mostly Strings.  I read in the data from the assets folder of my project, and parse it with GSON(the data is JSON).  This file is ~108KB in size.

For the life of my application, all data is being passed around as intent extras.  This is very convenient as i don't have to worry about re-loading the data from the assets folder again, app shutdown recovery is all taken care of, and i don't need to manage an SQLite database(versioning, queries, etc).

**Problem:**
I find that passing these extras around can become quite slow(starting an activity with ALL the data takes maybe 1.5 seconds or more). I can't seem to show any "loading" dialog either, as it seems to be a blocking call to start an activity and attach extras.

**Question(s):**
Should I avoid passing these extras around like I have described?  Is the best option using an SQLite database to interact with this data?  What suggestions do you have to avoid a lot of the fuss of SQLite databases/global static variables for accessing my application's data?

Slapping my JSON data into data model classes and passing them as intent extras is easy and nice(seemingly), and i don't want to give it up!

Comment: Also consider public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and followed the solution you already depicted. I used an SQLite DB to store the information, then passed only unique ids as intent extra and displayed a "loading..." progress dialog on the called activity while I accessed the DB.

Prolly using SQLite is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you load the data to the Application class, onCreate of the Application class, and then access from every activity there?

Comment: I would still have to check for an application shutdown on every create

Comment: True, but you can manage it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063550/android-best-way-to-save-data-stored-in-application-singleton-class/